# Issues with pushing to vector value of unordered_map in distributed protocol

Tags: c++, sockets, c++14, distributed-computing

We are implementing a socket programming protocol and have run into a bug that has baffled us.  The replica object receives multiple incoming messages of the same type and needs to keep a list of the messages received.  The problem is when we push an int on to the vector associated with the key, the code apparently returns without printing.  Below is our current output from the receiving replica when we run this code:

```
Signshare message received.
Signshare message received from replica: 1
This replica is a c_collector
The receiving view number is the same as this replicas view number. PASSED!
No previous signshare message with sequence s was accepted for view v.  PASSED!
In push_seq_signshare
SHOULD PRINT 4 TIMES!!!!!: 
Signshare message received.
Signshare message received from replica: 0
This replica is a c_collector
The receiving view number is the same as this replicas view number. PASSED!
No previous signshare message with sequence s was accepted for view v.  PASSED!
Signshare message received.
Signshare message received from replica: 3
This replica is a c_collector
The receiving view number is the same as this replicas view number. PASSED!
No previous signshare message with sequence s was accepted for view v.  PASSED!
Signshare message received.
Signshare message received from replica: 2
```

We desire the line `SHOULD PRINT 4 TIMES!!!!!:` to print 4 times, but it does not.

We have a private attribute in the replica class that keeps track of message ids of in coming messages.  It is an unordered_map of the form: key = make_pair(int, int); value = vector

Here is what the declaration looks like:

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>, pair_hash> accepted_sequence_signshare;
```

We found it necessary to create a struct to pass into the unordered map declaration (the pair_hash parameter above) to make the key hashable and this is what that struct looks like:

```
struct pair_hash
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) const
    {
        auto h1 = std::hash<T1>{}(p.first);
        auto h2 = std::hash<T2>{}(p.second);

        // Mainly for demonstration purposes, i.e. works but is overly simple
        // In the real world, use sth. like boost.hash_combine
        return h1 ^ h2;
    }
};
```

Our program is rather complicated (it is a distributed socket programming protocol) but we believe the relevant code snippet that is causing the bug is within one of our message handling functions.

```
void handleSIGNSHARE(message &msg, replica *r)
```

{

```
cout << "Signshare message received." << endl;
int recv_repID;
int recv_v;
int recv_s;
msg >> recv_repID >> recv_v >> recv_s;

cout << "Signshare message received from replica: " << recv_repID << endl;

cout << "This replica is a c_collector" << endl;
if (r->v == recv_v)
{
    cout << "The receiving view number is the same as this replicas view number. PASSED!" << endl;

    // no previous signshare message with sequence s was accepted for view v
    if (r->validate_view_sequence_signshare(recv_repID, recv_v, recv_s))
    {
        cout << "No previous signshare message with sequence s was accepted for view v.  PASSED!" << endl;
        // third condition:  threshold signature sigma(h) passes verification unimplemented

        // We believe through debugging that this line is the line with the bug.
        r->push_sequence_signshare(recv_repID, recv_v, recv_s);

        // This print statement should print 4 times (all nodes in the network send this message type to this replica
        // with 4 replicas in the network.  It only prints 1 time.
        cout << "SHOULD PRINT 4 TIMES!!!!!: " << r->get_size_for_view_sequence_signshare(recv_v, recv_s) << endl;

        //)(UJKLNLSNDFLKNLK) Only want this to run once.  Take care of the race condition that can occur here
        if (r->get_size_for_view_sequence_signshare(recv_v, recv_s) >= sig_N)
        {

            msg.setID(FULLCOMMITPROOF);
            msg << r->s << r->v << r->repID;
            r->sendToAll(msg);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No previous signshare message with sequence s was accepted for view v.  PASSED!" << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "The receiving view number is NOT the same as this replicas view number. FAILED!" << endl;
}
```

}

The line that we think is causing the issue is listed above, but just for clarity:

```
r->push_sequence_signshare(recv_repID, recv_v, recv_s);
```

Finally, below is the method called above in full:

```
void push_sequence_signshare(int r, int v, int s)
{
    mtx_signshare.lock();
    cout << "In push_seq_signshare" << endl;
    if (accepted_sequence_signshare.find(std::make_pair(v, s)) == accepted_sequence_signshare.end())
    {
        std::vector<int> vec;
        accepted_sequence_signshare.emplace(std::make_pair(v, s), vec);
    }

    accepted_sequence_signshare[std::make_pair(v, s)].push_back(r);

    mtx_signshare.unlock();
}
```

**What we have tried**

We have been debugging our output for the last 2-3 hours have tried different implementations of push_sequence_signshare(int r, int v, int s).  Essentially we want the function to just push the integer on to the vector associated with key = (v,s).  We have tried different methods of declaring the attribute (instead of having the value be std::vector, we tried std::vector*) but had no success.  We have also tried different methods of inserting into the unordered_map such as emplace, insert and map[key].push_back(value).

Assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have not said what your problem is - unless I missed it sowmewhere

Comment: plus surely you can make a 10 line test program for that map structure

Comment: I added detail to the post to clarify the problem.  I don't think it was very clear.  Please let me know if you require more detail.

Comment: The thing is with the 10 line tester, there is another print statement cout << "In push_seq_signshare" << endl; that should also print 4 times located on line three of the function void push_sequence_signshare(int r, int v, int s).  We don't correctly print there either.

Comment: there is no way we can debug this

Comment: Dang, could you explain why?  Not enough info in the post?  The program is large, and I have tried to break it down to just the essential parts.

Comment: Perhaps you are blocked in the call to mtx_signshare.lock() ?  Could be a deadlock or it could be that somebody forgot to unlock it the last time they used it (very easy to do if an exception is thrown and you aren’t using RAII to manage your locks)

Comment: We were able to get past the bug with a workaround, but never understood how to solve it.  Should this question be closed?  I'm not sure the protocol.